# Vim popup dialog cant be resized

Tags: vim

I've read in popup documentation that `resize` option allow the popup to be resized.

```
resize  TRUE to allow the popup to be resized with the mouse
        by grabbing at the bottom right corner.  Has no effect
        if the popup does not have a border.
```

So I stared creating dialog like this to try, ...

```
call popup_dialog('Popup Dialog Content', #{
    \ time: 15000,
    \ title: "Title",
    \ border: [],
    \ resize: 1,
    \ })
```

The good news is that a little arrow appears at the bottom right corner. The bad news is that the popup dialog is not resizable actually. What's wrong? Maybe the border option? Any suggestion to fix this? I am reading popup.txt documentation without achieve the desired target.

[image]

---

My vim version is:

> VIM - Vi IMproved 8.2 (2019 Dec 12, compiled Jun 26 2021 10:02:55)
> Garbage after option argument: "-version" More info with: "vim -h"

Comment: Your snippet works fine, here. Maybe a bug in your specific Vim version?

Comment: maybe an obvious question, but is the mouse enabled? e.g. `:set mouse=a`. also what is your setup? on my main terminal (`st`) it didn't work, on `xterm` it worked fine, but if I run it inside `tmux` it doesn't work, I suspect I have to enable the mouse even on `tmux`'s config.

Comment: Mouse is enabled but for example I cant resize NERDtree. The mouse scrolling works fine. But there is some configurations on iTermi or in Terminal tied to mouse that are not working fine on my machine.